# Using functions in mustache.js in express 3.0

Tags: node.js, express, mustache

I'm new to mustache.js and using it in express 3.0 in node.js and I want to use a helper function for formatting time in templates.

In app.js:

```
app.locals({
  helper: {
    friendly_time: require('./libs/util').friendly_time
  }
});
```

friendly_time is a function `function friendly_time(date){ ... }`, date is a `Date` object.

In index.hjs:

```
{{#articles}}
  <div class="org-articles">
    <ul class="org-articles-list">
      <li class="org-articles-item">
        <a class ="org-article-title" href="/o/{{title}}">
        {{title}}
        </a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;
        <span class="org-article-mtime">
          {{#helper.friendly_time}}
            {{mtime}}
          {{/helper.friendly_time}}
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
{{/articles}}
```

`articles` is an array containing objects like:

```
{
    title: 'title',                           // a string
    mtime: new Date() // a js Date object
}
```

And then the process throw error:

```
TypeError: Object {{mtime}} has no method 'getFullYear'
```

I know `articles[i].mtime` is treated as a string `{{mtime}}` and that causes the error. But I don't know how correct this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use three braces so that `mustache` doesn't try to clean the input data.  Though I'm not positive what it does with Date objects.

```
{{#helper.friendly_time}}
    {{{mtime}}}
{{/helper.friendly_time}}
```

The other option is to update `friendlyTime` so that it can also accept a string and convert it into a date object before attempting to call `getFullYear`.

```
function friendly_time(date){
    if(!date.getFullYear) {
        date = new Date(date);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: `TypeError: Object {{{mtime}}} has no method 'getFullYear'` The error still exists. Update the function will not correct it because what I pass to the function is the string `{{{mtime}}}` or `{{mtime}}`, not its value(a Date object or String object)!